# MBProgressHUD not working with category

Tags: objective-c, api, ios8, mbprogresshud

I have created one category class. As my application is working mostly on API calls. So I have used MBProgressHUD to show loading indicator while my API is loading.

```
-(void)loading {
    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:79.0/255.0 green:79.0/255.0 blue:79.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [HUD show:YES];
}
```

and On result I have written,

```
[HUD hide:YES];
```

But, I need to write above code in each and every file. So I thought category is the best way to reduce code repetition. If I put loading method in category then simply I call it with

```
[self loading];
```

On result my HUD is not hiding. I know there is conflict in HUD creation.
Because the HUD which is created in category file is differ from where I am trying to Hide it. I don't know how to handle it.

I have used category for very first time so not have deep knowledge about it.

Can anyone help me out here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Custom class (***NSObject*** subclass) with a Class Method with an argument of ***UIView*** described as below.

Below are two methods (in a new custom class for ProgressHUD) which will be helpful to you to use ***MBProgressHUD*** in ***UIViewController*** category.

```
+(void)showLoading:(UIView *)onView
{
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:onView];
    [onView addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:79.0/255.0 green:79.0/255.0 blue:79.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [HUD show:YES];
}

+(void)hideView
{
    [HUD hide:YES];
}
```

Now create a ***UIViewController*** category in which below will be two methods only. These methods will be helpful to show the progress hud in your view controller using category.

***UIViewController*** category methods.

```
-(void)showProgressHUD
{
    [MBProgressHUDCustom showLoading:self.view];
}

-(void)hideProgressHUD
{
    [MBProgressHUDCustom hideView];
}
```

Please try with above way. Hope this helps.
Good Luck!!!